# I want to see the detail of the purchase React Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a shopping list but I want to see the detail in the same list. With what element can I make the touch of the arrow to show me the detail.

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwZ9z.png)

```
<List {...props} >
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit" expand={<ItemsProductos />}>
            <TextField source="id" />   
            <TextField source="numero" label="Numero Comprobante" />
            <DateField source="fecha" />
        </Datagrid>
 </List>
```

Comment: You've already found the `expand` prop. What is your problem with it exactly? Is it how to write the `ItemsProductos` component? Please be more specific.

Comment: yes but i cant see the detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-admin will pass the current `record` to the component used as `expand` prop, so you can write your `<ItemProductos>` component as follows:

```
const ItemProductos == ({ record }) => (
    <span>{record.fecha}</span>
);
```

This is documented in the react-admin documentation:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#expand